# iText 2.1.7 regression - update metadata creator and producer

Tags: itext

While upgrading from iText 2.1.3 to iText 2.1.7 I noticed a change in behavior. The input PDF file is coming from Adobe Indesign and the goal is to change the Application and PDFProducer properties to something I want.

Below is the relevant piece of code :
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;
            PdfReader pdfReader = null;

```
        pdfReader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(source), null);
        HashMap info = pdfReader.getInfo();

        info.put( "Producer", "Myself");
        info.put( "Creator", "Myself");

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(source+"stamped.pdf");

        pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream, '\0', true);  // append mode
        pdfStamper.close();
        pdfReader.close();
```

So, before, using itext 2.1.3, after running a pdf through the code above, I would see the ***Application and PDFProducer*** changed to "Myself" when opening the file in Adobe Reader (File, Properties). That's what I expect

With itext 2.1.7, the **Application** property does not change and the **PDFProducer** property has the text "modified using iText 2.1.7 by ..." appended.

Using iText 5.4.5, the **Application** property is changed but the **PDFProducer** update behaves just like in 2.1.7

Any idea what happened and if there is something I can do to fix this?

thanks
Cristian

Comment: If you use iText, you are not allowed to change the producer line (see the note about this in the source code).

Comment: *While upgrading from iText 2.1.3 to iText 2.1.7* - this sounds like *while upgrading from Win95  to Win98*, both actions essentially ridiculous in a time of iText 5.5.x and Windows 8.x and beyond.

Comment: @mkl, You do know that iText 5 is not for free, right?

Comment: Neither is 2.1.7. It allows more than 5.x but not everything; e.g. it does not allow you to do what you want....even though this is not as clearly communicated as the restrictions of 5.x are.

Comment: @mkl, I wasn't clear. We use and pay for iText 5 for certain components and use iText 2.1.x in other components. To move from 2.1.x to 5.x.x would cost money in our context.

Comment: Hi christian, you need to patch itext 2.1.7 to correctly set the producer. Since the LPGL license covers the source code your are perfectly able to do so. If it is ethically right to disagree with the authors wishes you have to decide for yourself ;-) And since you patched iText you need to provide that change to your users (=comply to LGPL rules)...

Comment: @Lonzak *If it is ethically right to disagree with the authors wishes you have to decide for yourself ;-)* - this comment  can be interpreted as a call to *ignore the wishes of the author of the software you want to use*, and if this is no misinterpretation, such attitude are a major cause for ever stricter software licenses . Furthermore your legal position is questionable, at least several legislatures will honor the wishes of software authors which like this one are anchored in the source.

Comment: @mkl: No, it wasn't a call to ignore the wishes of the authors. Nearly pointing out that some things are covered by the LGPL and other things aren't. Don't get me wrong - I am for 100% license "obeying" but 100% license compliance + scanning all lines for potential autor wishes or other violations is difficult up-to impossible - it is like asking for 120% (where one doesn't exactly know what those 20% are about) ...

Comment: I  don't expect anyone merely *using* iText to have read that in-source comment. But I think anyone *adapting the code* in that respect (manipulating those very document properties) will see the comment. Thus, in my eyes those people trying to change the code like you say are well aware of the fact that they are counteracting the explicit wishes of the author. Furthermore, many licensing procedures do expect you to know these facts.

Comment: I saw adaptions of the code changing the producer in a totally different area, so people don't necessary stumble over this comment. And secondly the LGPL licensing procedure doesn't expect it (Other licenses may do it but thats not relevant here).